# Command to Generate both a Routing Module & Component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-cli

Is any way to create a `routing.module.ts` while generating a new module in angular-cli application other than creating it manually?

I recently started implementing lazy loading in my application and would like to combine both operations in one step.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

There is no separate command to create *routing.module* file. But, that can be created while on the creation of the module:

```
ng generate module [module-name] --routing
```

or the shorthand version of the command:

```
ng g m [module-name] --routing
```

... will create the module and add the mappings/metadata linkings.

---

I was searching about this a bit and found some article which has a very good explanation for different kind of commands.

[The Ultimate Angular CLI Reference](https://www.sitepoint.com/ultimate-angular-cli-reference/)

Comment: Hi Saiyaff Farouk, the above command creates both module.ts and routing.module.ts together at the same.

Is it possible to generate routing.module.ts alone since I already have one module.ts .

Comment: @Dhana I don't think that can be possible with a command for the scenario of 'Is it possible to generate routing.module.ts alone since I already have one module.ts'. To overcome this you can try writing your own schematic. But, let me do a bit of a further research and see whether what you want is available already in any sorta forms

Comment: You can generate `my-routing.module.ts` for an existing `my.module.ts` with `ng generate module my-routing --module my --flat`. Then add `RouterModule` to the new routing module as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990030/how-to-add-a-routing-module-to-an-existing-module-in-angular-cli-version-1-1-1/54635253).

Answer (score 28):

Module with Routing Create CMD :-

```
ng g m [ModuleName] --routing
```

Comment: it's better to create only routing files in that you've forgotten while generate the module

Answer (score 21):

Late but very useful.

```
ng g m about --module app --route about
```

The above command will generate about module with about component and add lazy load route at app module for routing about route.

Comment: Indeed very helpful - although i faced *"Couldn't find a route declaration in /src/app/app.module.ts"* in the first place, when using your command like this. What finally helped was passing the full file name of the app's routing module: `--module app.routing.ts`. Got the hint from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69779475/12924116.

Answer (score 16):

I am late to the party :) but here is how I generate a `module`, `routing` for the module and `component` all at one go and inside the same directory

From the `src/app/` directory type in the following command to generate a module, routing and component called 'my-page'

```
ng g m my-page --routing=true && ng g c my-page --skip-tests=true -m=my-page
```

If you want the tests to be generated then do not use the `--skip-tests` argument.

Answer (score 15):

Creates both module and routing simultaneously in the same folder.

```
ng g m sub-folder/module-name --routing
```

Creates the only module.

```
ng g m  sub-folder/module-name
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

To create a module with routing(lazy load importing), module routing, and a component that loaded at your routing
you can write by following the syntax

```
ng g m [myModule_name] --route [myRoute_path_name] --module [routing_module_name]
```

Example :

```
ng g m public --route public --module app
```

[image]

Comment: Another example 
ng g m features/courses --route courses --module app

Answer (score 6):

1. To generate component: `ng g c componanentName` or `ng g c sub-folder/componentName`
2. To generate module or routing module use: `ng g m sub-folder/moduleName --routing`

Answer (score 5):

**Simple command for Create a Module with routing..**

```
 ng g m [module_name] --routing
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can use**

```
// module and routing
-> ng g m name --routing

// component with module and routing
-> ng g c name && ng g m name --routing
-> ng g m name --routing && ng g c name -m=name`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ng generate module ModulName --flat --module=app
```

Answer (score 1):

1-if you want generate a routing in a folder:

```
ng g m [modelName] --routing
```

2-if you want to generate a routing in the same folder:

```
ng g m [modelName] --flat --routing --modele=app
```

3-generate a componenet with model routing:

```
ng g c [modelName] && ng g m [modelName] --routing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a module, routing, and component all at one go like this:

```
ng g m vast-urls --routing=true && ng g c vast-urls --skip-tests=true -m=vast-urls
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

`PowerShell`

This is a PowerShell function based on the other answers, which should be preloaded in the powersehll profile.

```
function Set-RoutingModule {
    
    param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
           [string]$Name );

    # Create Component
    & ng g c $Name  
     
    # Check the exit code
    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
      # Create Module

      & ng g m $Name --routing=true

      & write-host "Success" -ForegroundColor Green
      
    } else {
      # Handle the error
      & write-host "Error executing ng g m command." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

##### Usage

```
 Set-RoutingModule About
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to create routing file

```
**ng g m modulename --routing**
```

Comment: That’s what the top-voted, accepted answer already says, but with a lot more detail.