# How to add a routing module to an existing module in angular CLI version 1.1.1?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have created a module in using angular CLI and forget to add --routing while it's creation, now i want to add a routing module to it.

`ng init --routing` won't help in angular CLI version 1.1.1

Comment: Well, add the code by yourself. Or generate another module with routing, and copy and paste the generated code.

Comment: new version of angular cli doesn't support ng init

Answer (score 79, accepted):

That's not a problem at all.

Just add the routing manually.

All that the `--routing` flag does, in addition to adding `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app.component.html`, is add q `RouterModule.forRoot()` call in a separate module called `AppRoutingModule`, and include that module in the `imports` of `AppModule`.

So, in `app.module.ts`, it adds `AppRoutingModule` to the `imports` of your `AppModule`.

The `AppRoutingModule` is defined as `app-routing.module.ts`, which is created [from this template](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/module/files/__name%40dasherize%40if-flat__/__name%40dasherize__-routing.module.ts.template).

It's very small that I'll copy it here:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: []
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The `{path: '', children:[]}` is just a placeholder that you are expected to replace (I know because I added it to the source code). It just makes sure the router doesn't complain about the `<router-outlet>` when you don't have any routes.

So, back to the question, **what should you do?** Either copy the file to your project, to look just like the original CLI, and add `AppRoutingModule` to your `AppModule`'s `imports`...

Or just add `RouterModule.forRoot([/* routes here */])` to your `AppModule`'s `imports` instead. It'll still work, with built-in support for lazy loading and everything else working just fine.

P.S.

Remember that to add child routes, you can always generate more modules with routing `ng generate module Foo --routing` regardless of whether you used the `--routing` flag with `ng new` or not. No configuration or any magic to worry about.

Comment: So is there any specific flag to generate child routes? or it'll automatically create child routes when I use `--routing` flag while creating a new module?

Comment: angular-cli (as of version 6 at least) always uses ```RouterModule.forChild()``` when generating a new module. Only when using `--routing` with `ng new` it uses ```RouterModule.ForRoot()``` as import in the routing-module.
There are no actual Routes defined by the cli anyways.

Comment: To be able to run the tests with the `ng test` successfully, you need to add `import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';` and `TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],...` in the `app.component.spec.ts` file.

Comment: Working as expected.

Comment: this does not seem to work for child routing modules that  you want to associate with a feature module; I created two simple feature modules with a single component for each module. one of the modules I specced "--routing" during creation, the other I tried to add manually after the fact. then I added the loadChildren subroutes to the routes of the AppRoutingModule. desipte being identical in almost every way, the <router-outlet> could not route to the feature component to which routing had been manually added to the feature module. I am using Angular 11, BTW

Answer (score 41):

1. `ng generate module app-routing --module app --flat`

   - Replace `app` with the name of your existing module
   - Replace `app-routing` with the name to give the routing module
2. In the new module, add `appRoutes` and `RouterModule.forRoot` or `RouterModule.forChild`.

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
   import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

   const appRoutes: Routes = [
       { path: 'some-path', component: SomeComponent }
   ];

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
       ],
       exports: [
           RouterModule
       ]
   })
   export class AppRoutingModule {}
   ```
3. Add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your component if needed (e.g., `app.component.html`)

[Source](https://angular.io/guide/router#refactor-the-routing-configuration-into-a-routing-module)