# Angular : Couldn't find a route declaration in /src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to add automatic routing for components generated using following command

```
ng generate module orders --route orders --module app.module
```

I get the error

```
Couldn't find a route declaration in /src/app/app-routing.module.ts.
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

 }
```

I also tried adding this line the app-routing file

```
export const routes: Routes = []
```

Still problem persits.How to fix this error?

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem when was using angular template.
Solution was to write routing file name explicitly

```
ng generate module customers --route customers --module app.routing.ts
```

Comment: I faced the same problem but i have edit the app.routing.ts file like this : https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/534

Answer (score 1):

Try to use command `ng generate module orders --route orders --module app-routing.module`, as described in [cli module documentation](https://angular.io/cli/generate#module-command) :

> `--route` The route path for a lazy-loaded module. When supplied, creates a component in the new module, and adds the route to that component in the Routes array declared in the module provided in the --module option.

Looks like [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) cli command (ng generate module customers --route customers --module app.module) works fine only while your file structure is close to default and it can easily find `routes` array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the routes to your Angular Module (@NgModule). Follows an example how to do it (more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/router)):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

// Import the RouterModule
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//import the routes from your app-routing file
import { routes } from './app-routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

    //Add the routes to your Angular Module
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

 }
```

Comment: That's the way I have always done it. Routing works in my app. However when I use the CLI command `ng generate module orders --route orders --module app.module` I get the error indicated by  the OP.

Answer (score 0):

*Run this command `ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app` to create `app-routing.module.ts` file*
*then add the code `const routes: Routes = [];` like this*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

*after that you can run your command*

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me:

first create my module by this code :

```
ng g module orders --routing
```

after that, I declare my component in my-module

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

if you wants to run this command to add module in project

```
ng generate module orders --route orders --module app.module
```

atleast create one route and bind it and them run the above command